# How many permutations are possible if we choose 3 elements at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,F}?

Tags: probability

How many permutations are possible if we choose 3 elements at a time from the list {A,A,B,C,F}?

As the Wolfram Alpha suggests: [The result should be 33.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations%20%5B%7BA%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CF%7D%2C%7B3%7D%5D)

But, $\frac{^{5}P_{3}}{2!} = 30$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Wolfram Alpha generates 33 items.

Comment: Sorry, why isn't the answer $60$?  After all, there are $5!=120$ ways to permute $\{A,A^*,B,C,F\}$ and then setting $A=A^*$ divides this by $2$.  What am I missing?

Comment: @lulu: I divided incorrectly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas And from the link it appears that the intended question was  altogether different.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you mean 3-permutations.

Choosing 2 As: $3 \times {3 \choose 1} = 9$

Choosing 1 A: $3! \times {3 \choose 2} = 18$

Choosing no As: $3! = 6$

Add them up to get 33

Comment: Why are you calculating permutations individually and then adding up the results? Isn't there any direct formula available?

Comment: Not every $3$-combination will include $2$As so you can't always divide by $2!$ as in your original formula.

Comment: You r seemingly using Combination to solve a Permutation problem. Is it possible to solve this by using one or more Permutation formula?

Comment: @anonymous  The combinations are used to select which letters are in the permutation.   If you choose two A's, you must choose one of the other three letters, which accounts for the factor $\binom{3}{1}$, and then choose which of the $3$ locations will hold the letter that is not an A.